# How do I retrieve a username with Python keyring?

Tags: python, windows, python-keyring

I have a Mercurial keyring on my Windows 7 machine. I am using the Python [`keyring`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/keyring) library to get user credentials from the Mercurial keyring.

I can retrieve the password for a given username with:

```py
keyring.get_password('Mercurial', 'user@@etc')
```

Is there a similar function to retrieve the username?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are expected to have stored the username somewhere else.

The keyring only stores the password, keyed by the application name and username.

Answer (score 12):

On Windows I was able to get both username and password (i.e. the "credentials") using

`c = keyring.get_credential("servicename", None)`

Note that this does not work on macOS, the `keyring` backend does not have capabilities to search for entries - i.e. you need to know the username. I suppose that native code would allow you to do this, though, see [official docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/keychain_items/searching_for_keychain_items)

Comment: Worth mentioning that you can access the username, password like so: `c.username` and `c.password`.

Comment: This is the most accurate answer.

Comment: Worth specifying `get_credential` is available from [Keyring 15.2.0](https://github.com/jaraco/keyring/blob/main/CHANGES.rst#1520) onwards.

Comment: Why the [official documentation](https://pypi.org/project/keyring/) does not say this?

Answer (score 9):

> Update: As of Keyring 15.2.0, [you can use `keyring.get_credential`
> instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74351348/3357935).

---

While `keyring` was only designed to store passwords, you can abuse `get_password` to store the username separately.

```
import keyring

# store username & password
keyring.set_password("name_of_app", "username", "user123")
keyring.set_password("name_of_app", "password", "pass123")

# retrieve username & password
username = keyring.get_password("name_of_app", "username")
password = keyring.get_password("name_of_app", "password")
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep the username paired with the password:

```
import keyring

service_id = "name_of_app"
username = "user123"

# store username & password
keyring.set_password(service_id, "username", username)
keyring.set_password(service_id, username, "pass123")

# retrieve username & password
username = keyring.get_password(service_id, "username")
password = keyring.get_password(service_id, username)
```

Credit to [Dustin Wyatt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31882203/3357935) & [Alex Chan](https://twitter.com/alexwlchan/status/964531327096717312) for this solution.

Comment: Is the key (not the password) stored securely in the keychain or does that "paired" solution expose the username?

Comment: @DylanYoung This depends on the backend. Pass for example stores the credentials as a path.So the username is part of that path and only the credential file is encrypted.

Answer (score 3):

You can retrieve a username with the `get_credential` function added in [keyring 15.2.0](https://github.com/jaraco/keyring/blob/main/CHANGES.rst#1520).

```
import keyring

keyring.set_password("example_service", "example_username", "example_password")
credentials = keyring.get_credential("example_service", None)
if credentials is not None:
    username = credentials.username  # example_username
    password = credentials.password  # example_password
```

Credit to [MShekow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54091770/3357935) and [Eelco van Villet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64241889/3357935) for providing a similar answer

Answer (score 2):

If you want to hide your username in the script as well you can use credentials of the keyring module. Also I would recommend to use the getpass library for the input of the password; this prevents the password to be printed to screen. Finally, you may want to have a delete credentials somewhere in your code as soon as you notice that the login failed. Otherwise the script restart without the prompt to the user. As a full example. Here is how you would retrieve the username and password

```
import getpass
import keyring
import requests

service_name = "Name of the keyring"
credentials = keyring.get_credential(service_name, None)
if credentials is None:
    username = input("Username: ")
    password = getpass.getpass()
    keyring.set_password(service_name,username, password)
else:
    username = credentials.username
    password = credentials.password
```

Then you can do your thing, for instance do a post using request to an api. If it fails, delete the keyring to force to ask the credenitials again.

```
response = requests.post('url_to_api', auth=requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth(username, password))
try:
    response.raise_for_status()
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
    keyring.delete_password(service_name, username)
    raise
```

If the login succeeds, the next time you don't have to input username and password again.

Comment: This response is elegant!