# remember password functionality in python

Tags: python, encryption, python-3.x, cryptography

basically, I want to have a login box, and the option to remember the password next time you log in. I know there are encryption modules out there, but they require a password to work in the first place. is there a way to get the password the user used to log into the computer, and use that to encrypt the password for my application?

so in a nutshell, how do I store a password securely for later use.

I'm using python 3, and my program needs to be crossplatform.

Comment: thanks for all your quick replies. I guess I never mentioned it but the username/password is used in my application and a 3rd party website it connects to, so I don't have to much control. I made the answer with the keyring the accepted one because it works the best in my case, but for other people, the other answers work will also.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I need to securely store a username and password in Python, what are my options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014953/i-need-to-securely-store-a-username-and-password-in-python-what-are-my-options)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need Keyring: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/keyring

Comment: Nice! Is it used in some project?

Comment: @Stefano I don't know much about it, just googled for 'python keychain' :) . What I do know is that OS's natively provide a way to store passwords securely.

Comment: Yes, I know, mentioned that in my answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the password the user used to log in to the computer.

And, if you could, you would not want to store it.

In fact, the OS doesn't even have the user's password. The OS has a *hash* of it, and when the user logs in, it hashes what the user types and checks that it matches.

---

Also, if you ask the user to log in with their system password, any savvy user is going to immediately mistrust your app and refuse to use it. Make them create a password, and then login with *that*, not their system password. And don't save the password, save a hash, just like the OS does.

If you want to verify that they've been authenticated by the OS… well, you already *know* that, or they couldn't have logged in to run your app. (If you're building a network server that allows remote login based on local accounts, that's a different story, but it's not relevant to your use case, and complicated, so I won't get into it here.)

---

If you want to allow someone to "stay logged in", you don't do that by saving their password. Instead, you create some kind of hard-to-fake "session key" when they log in, and store that somewhere. They don't have to log in again until you destroy the session key (which you do when they log out).

---

The one exception to "never store passwords" is when you need to act as a "proxy" for the user to some other application that needs their password. A well-designed application will provide a way for you to proxy the login properly, but many applications are not well-designed. Web browsers have to do this all the time, which is why most web browsers have a "remember my password at this site" checkbox.

In this case, you do want to store passwords, ideally encrypted by the OS on your behalf (e.g., using OS X's Keychain APIs), or, if not, encrypted by you code using some key that's generated from the user's "master password" (which you don't store).

---

Unfortunately, there is no real shortcut to learning how to design for security—or, rather, there are all kinds of shortcuts, and taking any one of them means your entire system ends up insecure and all the work you put into trying to secure it ends up useless.

The easy solution is to use complete off-the-shelf solutions.

If you want to design things yourself, you need at least a basic grounding in all of the issues. Start with one of Bruce Scheneier's "pop" books, *Secrets and Lies* or *Beyond Fear*. Then read his *Practical Cryptography* on designing cryptosystems, and *Applied Cryptography* on evaluating crypto algorithms. Then, once you realize how much you don't know and how important it is, learn everything you need for your problem, and then you can think about solving it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way out. If the application does not ask the user for a password, then it is not securely storing passwords, it's only doing... "things". In that case, don't give the user a false sense of security, use cleartext.

A notable exception is the GNOME login keyring (and equivalent on other platforms) not asking for a password, but it uses a trick: it encrypts data with your login password and decrypts them with the same when you enter it at startup.

If you are developing a web application with a local client, consider using OAuth instead of passwords.