# Using username and password safely in Python code

Tags: python, security, python-requests, windows-authentication, password-protection

I'm using the Python requests library to make a call to an API that requires Windows Authentication. In C# I have always used the Directory Services, which has allowed me to avoid putting passwords in any of my code or configurations. From what I have found online, it seems that my only option in Python is to have a password somewhere. I have a service account that I will use, but I need to store the password securely. What is the best way to securely store and retrieve a service account password in Python without hard coding plain text?

The code that I am currently using is below. I have the username and password stored in plain text in my configuration:

```
auth = HttpNtlmAuth(
    config.ServiceAccount["Username"], 
    config.ServiceAccount["Password"]
    )

content = requests.post(call_string, json=parameters, auth=auth)
```

Edit: I should mention that this will not be a user-facing application. It will run as a batch job. So there will not be any way for a user to enter the username/password while running the application.

Comment: I don't know much about Windows programming but why can't you use Directory Services? It shouldn't matter what language you are in, if it is a service available to the system you should be able to access it. Is it part of Active Directory? There are various packages to interface with that.

Comment: @Kevin K , Please refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014953/i-need-to-securely-store-a-username-and-password-in-python-what-are-my-options?noredirect=1&lq=1

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know I asked this question a while ago, but I found a better solution to the NTLM/Windows authentication. I used the `requests_negotiate_sspi` library to avoid any passwords:

```
from requests_negotiate_sspi import HttpNegotiateAuth
auth = HttpNegotiateAuth()

content = requests.post(call_string, json=parameters, auth=auth)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just not store the password at all and require the user to provide the password at runtime

```
import getpass
user = getpass.getuser()
password = getpass.getpass()
```

Otherwise, you could do something similar to git and just have the user store their password in plaintext in a config file in their home directory that you then read at runtime.

Comment: This application will run as a batch process, so there won't be any opportunity for a user to input their credentials.