# Python: Protect password argument when multiple calls are needed

Tags: python, lambda, passwords

I am implementing a class that represents a connection to e.g., an API/database, and want to provide a method to reconnect when the connection is lost (e.g., due to a timeout). The user provides a username and a password at initialization, which has to be in raw text due to API requirements.

I think one should NOT store the password in any instance variable; I am aware that [one may use the “keyring” library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014953/i-need-to-securely-store-a-username-and-password-in-python-what-are-my-options), but was wondering if there is any way that does not depend on external libraries and/or the password cannot be later revealed by any means.

One method I came up with is to use a lambda creator:

```py
class Connection:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         # other stuff
         password = input(“some message”)
         self.connection_handle = (lambda pass : (lambda : api.connect(password=pass))(password)
         del password
         self.conn = self.connection_handle()

    def reconnect(self):
         self.conn = self.connection_handle()
```

where for simplicity we assume only `password`, which is a raw password, is used by some API provided connection procedure `api.connect`.

I tried `inspect.showsource` and also examined other attributes of `connection_handle`. It seemed to me that one cannot find the value of the `password` anywhere. But I am not entirely sure.

**So here are my questions:**

1. Is this lambda creator method really secure in that `password` cannot be recovered even if one can access the instance of the `Connection`?
2. Is there any “standard paradigm” to deal with such scenarios when a method needs to be called several times with sensitive argument which one does not wish to store?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are missing a ':' at end of the __init__