# Python converted to .exe but the user needs to be able to edit files

Tags: python, selenium, pip, exe, py2exe

I made a script which automates some processes using Selenium and another Script where I store variables like password and email.

I converted it to an a `.exe` file but the user needs to be able to edit the `Details.py` file.

Is there any work around since as soon as I convert it to `.exe` theres no way for me to edit and save files?

Edit: Posted code to help with an answer:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep
from Details import *

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

url = "https://discordapp.com/channels/530588470905929729/538868623981412362"
driver.get(url)
email = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='email']")))
email.send_keys(Email)

password = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='password']")))
password.send_keys(Password + Keys.ENTER)

sleep(5)

textbox = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//textarea[@placeholder='Message #bot-commands']")))
textbox.send_keys("!work" + Keys.ENTER)

sleep(30)

driver.quit()
```

This is `Details.py`:

```
Password = "Password"
Email = "mail@mail.com"
```

Comment: is `details.py` just data, or is it code?

Comment: …Don’t convert it?  (If not, say why not!)

Comment: details.py is just two variables , one for password and one for email

Comment: because if i dont convert it my friends who want to use it need to install python and selenium

Comment: Change your code so that the password and email are read from a config file, or Windows registry.

Comment: @itsolidude Just don't have it as a python file that gets packages then. Store it as a `.txt` file or something externally and read it from the program using `open` just like any other text file. Storing it as a JSON or another format would make that easy.

Comment: how would i approach this?wouldnt that mean i need to use the JSON module

Comment: Yes, or just store in as a pickled dictionary, or a CSV, or a number of other formats. What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: I never really used JSON  tbh i tried it a couple times but that was it.

Comment: I posted my code so you may have a look at it

Comment: Why don't you make a txt file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to rethink the design of your program. It's not secure or user-friendly to edit .py files in order to alter saved credentials. I suggest you have a look around for already proven methods of storing sensitive information. There are lots of options out there and you can start with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014953/i-need-to-securely-store-a-username-and-password-in-python-what-are-my-options).