# How to secure a Python script SQL Server authentification

Tags: python, sql-server, security, password-protection

I am using a Python script to connect to a SQL Server database:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas 

server = 'SQL' 
database = 'DB_TEST' 
username = 'USER' 
password = 'My password' 

sql='''
SELECT *
FROM [DB_TEST].[dbo].[test]
'''
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)

data = pandas.read_sql(sql,cnxn)
cnxn.close()
```

The script is launched everyday by an automatisation tools so there is no physical user.

The issue is how to replace the password field by a secure method?

Comment: What do you mean by "replace the password field by a secure method" ?

Comment: you can also have the password be an environment variable and read that using `os.environ.get()`

Comment: I mean by a way to prevent from having a clear password in the script.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I need to securely store a username and password in Python, what are my options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014953/i-need-to-securely-store-a-username-and-password-in-python-what-are-my-options)

Comment: Specifically, this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53027302/7948962

Answer (score 0):

The automated script is still ran by a windows user. Add this windows user to the SQL-Server users and give it the appropriate permissions, so you can use:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas 

server = 'SQL' 
database = 'DB_TEST'

sql='''
SELECT *
FROM [DB_TEST].[dbo].[test]
'''
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(
    f'DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};Trusted_Connection=True;')

data = pandas.read_sql(sql,cnxn)
cnxn.close()
```

Comment: I have a login failed for user and I am not allowed to add a specific user as trusted connection

Comment: If you can't add your user, you will have to use a password. You can put it to places other than your code, but there always will be a vulnerability. (file, env variable, etc)

Comment: Yes that what I thought too there is no a strong solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am also interested in secure coding using Python .I did my own research to figure out available options, I would recommend reviewing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53027302/5912896) post as it summarize it all. Check on the listed options, and apply the one suits you better.