# Hiding sensitive information in Python

Tags: python, python-requests

I am creating a Python script which reads a spreadsheet and issues Rest requests to an external service. A token must be obtained to issue requests to the Rest service, so the script needs a username and password to obtain the `oauth2 token`.

What's the best or standard way to hide or not have visible information in the Python script?

Comment: Read it from an external file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I need to securely store a username and password in Python, what are my options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014953/i-need-to-securely-store-a-username-and-password-in-python-what-are-my-options)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a config file. Let's create a config file and name it `config.cfg`. The file structure should look more or less like this:

```
[whatever]
key=qwerertyertywert2345
secret=sadfgwertgrtujdfgh
```

Then in python you can load it this way:

```py
from configparser import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser()
config.read('config.cfg')

my_key = config['whatever']['key']
my_secret = config['whatever']['secret']
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, the most standard way to handle secrets in Python is by putting them in runtime configuration.

You can do that by reading explicitly from external files or using `os.getenv` to read from environment variables.

Another way is to use a tool like [python-decouple](https://pypi.org/project/python-decouple/), which lets you use the environment (variables), a .env file, and an .ini file in a cascade, so that developers and operations can control the environment in local, dev, and production systems.