# can I use integrated windows authentication with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape an internal web page with BeautifulSoup.  The web page itself is only open to certain users on our network and uses integrated Windows authentication.  I have a simple script below that works just fine, but I have to provide credentials.

```
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "internal page"
content = requests.get(url, auth=HttpNtlmAuth('domain\\myusername', 'mypw'))

result = BeautifulSoup(content.text, 'html.parser')

print(result)
```

Is it possible for me to run this in such a way that I don't have to provide my credentials, using integrated Windows authentication?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a closed [issue](https://github.com/requests/requests-ntlm/issues/66) at `requests-ntlm` repo with a question:

> Is there a way to authenticate with currently logged user's credentials instead of providing login/password directly inside the script?

And response from author of the lib:

> Not as far as I know....

---

Also take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014953/i-need-to-securely-store-a-username-and-password-in-python-what-are-my-options). There are some alternative ways to store your secrets.

Personally I prefer environment variables and something like `secrets.py`:

```py
import os

user = os.getenv('MY_USER')
password = os.getenv('MY_PASSWORD')
```

And then you could import your secrets from there:

```py
from secrets import user, password
```

---

Another non so lightweight option is to use `playwriht` or `selenium` to open real browser, which might be able to load page without hardcoded login and password