# Using O365 REST APIs can I then use Discovery APIs to find user's 0365 SharePoint servers via Oauth2?

Tags: rest, sharepoint, azure, office365

we've seen [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25110408/oauth2-for-sharepoint-365-rest) already and using the O365 REST API we have a working Oauth2 workflow that authenticates an O365 user and returns an access token.  Our question is: Once we have an access token for a user, how can we discover the user's SharePoint servers (and associated endpoints) without knowing the authenticated user's O365 SharePoint server URLs ahead of time?

Our application uses Oauth2 workflows to access data on behalf of users from GitHub, DropBox, Google Docs and other services, and typically once user permission has been granted and we have an access token there is a straightforward way of querying/retrieving the resources for the user via the access token.

Once we have an access token, we're calling the [O365 Discovery Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn776441(v=office.15).aspx).  If I'm reading [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn776441(v=office.15).aspx#DiscSvc_Services) correctly, we should be getting back ServiceInfo entries on a request to the O365 /Services endpoint with an access token, like this:

https://contoso-my.sharepoint.com/personal/alexd_contoso_com

https://contoso-my.sharepoint.com

But at present we only get back O365 File and Contact ServiceInfo entries, even though in the Azure Portal when we created our app we specified Office 365 SharePoint Online Delegated Permission ('Read List').

If there are different O365 endpoints we should be hitting once we have an access token in order to discover a user's SharePoint servers, or if we're using the Discovery Services wrong,  please provide a few pointers -- We want to solve this problem in a generic fashion based on Oauth2 workflow and don't want to prompt the user for things like O365 SharePoint Server URLs.

Lastly I'd mention that we're accessing this info in a purely RESTful fashion and we have no Windows-specific dependencies (in fact we're building things on the JVM) so a workable solution for us must not depend on Windows-only APIs or platforms.