# How to decrypt cookies in Chrome?

Tags: python, google-chrome, encryption, cookies, windows-10

Google stores cookies in a db file located at:

*C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cookies*

I've downloaded Sqlite database browser to help me look at these values. What surprises me is that about half of the cookie values shows as empty (including the one I need), even though they are obviously not.Obviously,they might be encrypted.

Is there any way to decrypt them? I'm working on a python project which needs the cookie value!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decrypt Chrome Linux BLOB encrypted cookies in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22973049/decrypt-chrome-linux-blob-encrypted-cookies-in-python) or [Decrypting Chromium cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23153159/decrypting-chromium-cookies/23727331#23727331)

Comment: Sorry ! I searched directly in stack exchange ,nothing helped ..so I posted this question...thanks for the help though :) @ctwheels

Comment: These links may also be useful to you: https://n8henrie.com/2014/05/decrypt-chrome-cookies-with-python/ and https://gist.github.com/DakuTree/428e5b737306937628f2944fbfdc4ffc

Comment: Marked it as a dupe. Aathwik, please comment if you think it is not.