# How to decrypt "encrypted_value" column in Chrome's Cookies Database?

Tags: sql, database, google-chrome, encryption, cookies

I just got my Chrome's "Cookies" file which has a .bin extension from my Windows 10 machine at the path:

C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\

Now, since I used to use just Firefox which doesn't encrypt it's cookies values in the cookies database, I don't know what to do about getting the value of cookies in the Chrome db.
Just by looking into it with SQLite Explorer I learned that values are encrypted in a special column of the table with the value BLOB and I can only get a binary format of it that is useless for me.

[image: img]

Now I saw many solutions over the Internet, with scripts mainly written in Python and Perl but no one worked for me.
At this point I really don't know how to handle the situation and I really need to get those cookies values.

I got skills in programming with Python 3 and Java but I'm not skilled enough about cookies and about the way Chrome encrypts them to write a decrypt script, so if you have any advice on where or how should I get started on this I would be grateful you to tell me.

Please don't report as a duplicate, since every other topic that I read about this didn't help me at all and I think that maybe starting a new question about this could help me find a better solution, thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decrypt Chrome Linux BLOB encrypted cookies in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22973049/decrypt-chrome-linux-blob-encrypted-cookies-in-python)